# Complexity of non-commutative range multiplication operation

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Let $G$ be a non-commutative group, such as $\operatorname{GL}_k(\mathbb F_p)$. Given a list $\vec{a}=(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in G^n$, we use $(p, q, x)$ to denote the operation that maps $\vec{a}$ to $(a_1, \cdots, a_{p-1}, a_p x, \cdots, a_q x, a_{q+1}, \cdots, a_n)$. Do we have an algorithm running in time complexity $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$, such that when input a sequence of operations $(p_i, q_i, x_i)_{i \leqslant l}$ where $l = O(n), p_i \leqslant q_i \leqslant n$, it computes the result of these operations on list $(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$?

When the group operation is commutative, it can be computed using a textbook segmented tree or Fenwick tree, where each operation takes time $O(\log n)$, and all these $l$ operations take time $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  What's the motivation, or the source where you originally encountered it?

Comment: What is $n$?  Is it the length of the original list?  If so, can you [edit] the post to state this explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in $O(n \log^2 n)$ time.  Build a balanced binary tree over the $n$ leaves.  Store a group element in each node.  Initialize the tree by storing the element $1$ in each node.

Identify each leaf with an index $j$ in the range $1 \le j \le n$.  The idea is that, at any point during the execution of the algorithm, the value of the $j$th list element will be $g_1 g_2 \dots g_k$, where $g_1,\dots,g_k$ are the group elements obtained by traversing the tree starting at leaf $j$ and proceeding upwards until you reach the root.

Define the pushdown($v$) operation as follows: given an internal node $v$ of the tree, let $\ell,r$ be $v$'s left and right children, and $g_v,g_\ell,g_r$ be the group elements stored at $v,\ell,r$.  Then we replace $g_v,g_\ell,g_r$ with $1,g_\ell g_v, g_r g_v$.  This takes $O(1)$ time.

Define the megapush($w$) operation as follows: we iterate through the nodes on the path from the root to $w$, executing pushdown($v$) on each such node $v$ (starting with the root first and proceeding downwards).  This takes $O(\log n)$ time, as the height of the tree is $O(\log n)$, since the tree is balanced.

Identify each internal node with a range of indices, namely, the range of indices associated with the leaves that are descendants of that node.  Any range of indices $[\ell,u]$ can be written as the disjoint union of $O(\log n)$ ranges $[\ell_i,u_i]$, such that each $[\ell_i,u_i]$ is the range associated with a node of the tree.

To handle the operation $(p,q,x)$, express the range $[p,q+1]$ as a disjoint union of $O(\log n)$ ranges $[\ell_i,u_i]$ as above.  For each node $v$ associated with one of these ranges, first execute megapush($v$), then multiply the group element stored at $v$ by $x$.  In other words, if $g_v$ was previously stored at that node (after the megapush), replace it with $g_v x$.  This takes $O(\log^2 n)$ time, since we call megapush on $O(\log n)$ nodes.

Finally, after all of these operations, you can traverse the nodes of the tree in pre-order, executing pushdown($v$) on each node $v$.  (In other words, first you execute pushdown on the root, then on its two children, then on its four grandchildren, and so on.)

Then you can read off the results, as the leaf associated with index $j$ will store the value of the $j$th list item after executing all operations.

Each operation takes $O(\log^2 n)$ time ($O(\log n)$ time to execute megapush on each of $O(\log n)$ nodes), and there are at most $n$ operations, so the operations take $O(n \log^2 n)$ time.  All other operations can be done in $O(n)$ time.

Therefore, the total running time is $O(n \log^2 n) = O(n^{1+o(1)})$.